# Is there an application like Clipper for Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, software-recommendation

Is there any software like "Clipper" for Mac?
I am looking for an application like [this.](http://www.intelexual.com/products/yc3/)

Comment: Could you list the expected functionality of the app you are seeking? This will allow your question to be complete even if the link you provided becomes unavailable at some point in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find something like what you are looking for here [9 Crafty Clipboard Utilities for Mac](http://mac.appstorm.net/roundups/utilities-roundups/9-crafty-clipboard-utilities-for-mac/). Also [TextExpander](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/) might be of interest too.

Answer (score 2):

Try [ClipMenu](http://www.clipmenu.com), it's a nice clipboard manager that supports multiple types such as:

- Plain text
- Rich Text Format (RTF)
- Rich Text Format Directory (RTFD)
- PDF
- Filenames
- URL
- TIFF image
- PICT image of object such as text, URL, images.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) and its Powerpack for clipboard history. Aside from the actual keeping of history, you can save snippets that you use often and call them up with a combination of letters and search among recently copied texts.

The price of the Powerpack might seem a little steep for just a clipboard history keeper, but Alfred can do so much more. It has become one of my most essential apps, so give it a try.